# How to grab a uv sphere to make a sausage arm?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

I am trying to reproduce a part of a video https://youtu.be/iYNdfef1Uog?t=3 to try to create a basic human shape (I'm just a beginner in sculpting i want just to make the basic human shape to begin).

As you can see he seems to be using the grab brush and manage to make a uv sphere into a sausage arm (or leg depending of the situation). like in the screenshot below :

[image]

But when I try to do the same on my uv sphere with the grab brush, I get a result like this :

[image]

He seems to be using a radius of 97 px but I can't get the same result. I think it might due to the fact the brush in only grabbing the front of the sphere but i'm not sure if it's the problems

Comment: Use a large radius and grab the bottom of the sphere and it should work